# How I can hide out of stock product variations on variable products?

Tags: woocommerce

I want hide out of stock combitanoins in variatable products. But if product is simple (without variations) - display this product. I try this code, but nothing works.

```
function kfg_show_backorders( $is_visible, $id ) {
    $product = new wC_Product( $id );

    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->backorders_allowed() ) {
        $is_visible = false;
    }

    return $is_visible;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_is_visible', 'kfg_show_backorders', 10, 2 );
```